# MySQL 5.7 how to pass main query data into sub sub query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am using MySQL 5.7

I have two tables: `device` and `groups`.
One group can have many devices.

In `device` table, there are columns like this:

```
id   |   groups_id
--------------------
'1'  |   '000111'
'2'  |   '000222'
'3'  |   '000333'
```

In `groups` table , there is a column `parent` to store parent group id (to represent hierarchy group structure).

```
id        |   name  |  parent
---------------------------------
'000111'  |   'G1'  |  ''
'000222'  |   'G2'  |  '000111'
'000333'  |   'G3'  |  '000222'
```

And this is what my desired output:

```
device_id | device_groups_id  |  groups_path_json
-----------------------------------------------------
'1'       | '000111'          |  '["G1"]'
'2'       | '000222'          |  '["G2","G1"]'
'3'       | '000333'          |  '["G3","G2","G1"]'
```

I write a sub query used to find hierarchy group's parent name.
And I need to pass `device`.`groups_id` from main query into sub query.

```
SELECT
    `device`.`id` AS `device_id`,
    `device`.`groups_id` AS `device_groups_id`,
    (SELECT CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT('"', `groups`.`name`, '"'), ']')
     FROM 
        (SELECT
            @current_group AS `current_group_id`, 
            (SELECT 
                @current_group := `parent`
             FROM 
                `groups`
             WHERE 
                `id` = `current_group_id`
            ) AS `parent_group_id`
         FROM 
            (SELECT @current_group := `device`.`groups_id`) initial, groups
         WHERE 
            @current_group <> ''
        ) result
     LEFT JOIN `groups` ON `result`.`current_group_id` = `groups`.`id`
    ) AS 'groups_path_json'
FROM `device`
;
```

Then I got this error:

```
Error Code: 1109. Unknown table 'device' in field list
```

And I don't know how to pass `device`.`groups_id` from main query into sub query.

```
(SELECT @current_group := `device`.`groups_id`) initial, groups
```

Can any please help me in this scenario?

Comment: You cannot. Even if you'll move the subquery to FROM, you'll not provide correct UDV evaluation order.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version and post the task (not the query which you want to use for to solve your task), including source DDL, sample data and desired output.

Comment: OK I have added more detail about my question

Comment: Tree building on MySQL 5.7 cannot be performed in single query (or the data must have some restrictions and rules, for example, "the parent is always above its child while sorting by `id`"). If no such restriction then only stored procedure may solve this task (and I recommend to use this solution in any case).

Comment: @Akina Do you mean to move my sub query code into a stored function or a stored procedure?

Comment: No, convert the whole query to iterational stored procedure (SP cannot be used as a rowsource of a query).